# Why is my password reset not working? rails tutorial ch 12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid, railstutorial.org

Currently following Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial on chapter 12, about password reset. I am using sendgrid to send an account activation email in production. However, I receive no email. The code seems to be working and producing an email template in the Heroku logs but it never arrıves in my ınbox. I had a problem before saying that my sendgrid account was not verified and I have solved this and it is now verified. (apart from whitelabelling stage, not sure if this makes a difference). The sendgrid account is now activated but I am still getting various errors in the Heroku logs and I need help in understanding them.

Heroku logs: As can be seen from the Heroku logs below. The activation email is generated but never arrives. Then, there are a few errors at the end which I don't know how to deal with.

My questions are:

- What is an internal server error?
- What does "535 authentication failed" mean?
- Which account is "account disabled" referring to? sendgrid? (it is not 
  disabled I just logged in)
- What is wrong with my `send_password_reset_email` method? As far as I see it is the same as the code in the tutorial.
- What is wrong with my `create' method in`app/controllers/password_resets_controller.in line rb:15`

I've followed all steps in the tutorial and neither the password reset email arrives nor the account activation email. What am I missing?

```
2017-12-07T03:40:03.290409+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-12-07T03:40:03.290353 #10]  INFO -- : [f8b6a375-a51d-4d50-b061-30e5a82ea5e3] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 457ms (ActiveRecord: 22.0ms)
2017-12-07T03:40:03.290977+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-12-07T03:40:03.290923 #10] FATAL -- : [f8b6a375-a51d-4d50-b061-30e5a82ea5e3]   
2017-12-07T03:40:03.291023+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-12-07T03:40:03.290980 #10] FATAL -- : [f8b6a375-a51d-4d50-b061-30e5a82ea5e3] Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: account disabled
2017-12-07T03:40:03.291024+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2017-12-07T03:40:03.291064+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-12-07T03:40:03.291025 #10] FATAL -- : [f8b6a375-a51d-4d50-b061-30e5a82ea5e3]   
2017-12-07T03:40:03.291111+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-12-07T03:40:03.291074 #10] FATAL -- : [f8b6a375-a51d-4d50-b061-30e5a82ea5e3] app/models/user.rb:77:in `send_password_reset_email'
2017-12-07T03:40:03.291112+00:00 app[web.1]: [f8b6a375-a51d-4d50-b061-30e5a82ea5e3] app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

Method in app/controllers/password_resets_controller.in line rb:15:

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :get_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]    # Case (1) expired password reset


  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
```

app/models.user:

```
  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end
```

EDIT: SMTP settings:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'https://still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: the error you're seeing (`Net::SMTPAuthenticationError `) makes me think this isn't to do with your code, it's with your authentication to the email service which you haven't shown here.

Comment: Have you set your sendgrid username and password as env variables on a heroku?

Comment: @max pleaner , I have added smpt settings. is this the file that you need to see for the authentication of the email?

Comment: @inveterateliterate , i believe so, but is there a way to check this? i am not 100%

Comment: @Owen if you log into Heroku and navigate to this app, you should find a nav item called “Settings”. On that tab there should be a section called “Config Variables” with a button that says “reveal config variables”. Click that button and some fields will appear. Those are the fields you need to fill out with your sendgrid username and password (like your `application.yml`)

Comment: @inveterateliterate i have checked and the password and usename are filled in correctly as i thought. so this is not the problem. what is application.yml. i dont think my project has this

Comment: Try setting the domain attribute in your SMTP settings to be `root_url` instead of `heroku.com`

Comment: @inveterateliterate. no luck , i get the same error

Comment: I don’t think this will do it but instead of `root_url` I saw you defined what that should be as `host` above. Sorry I just usually call it `root_url`. So where I said write `root_url` write `host`.